# Type alias in separate file: PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'dict' because it has a __init__ constructor

Tags: python, pytest, python-typing, python-poetry

I am using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), Python 3.10, and [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/). I try to separate type aliases in a separate test file (that can be included from different test files) but when running `pytest` I get a warning about `cannot collect test class 'dict'`. Here is a minimal example (my real program is more complex):

```
$ poetry new --src myproject
$ cd myproject
$ poetry add --group=dev pytest

$ cat <<'END' > src/myproject/main.py
def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:  # This is the function that we will test with pytest
    return a + b
END

$ cat <<'END' > tests/common.py
TestDataDict = dict[str, str]  # This is the type alias in a separate file
END

$ cat <<'END' > tests/test_main.py  # This is the test file
import pytest
import myproject.main
from tests.common import TestDataDict

@pytest.fixture()
def get_dict() -> TestDataDict:
    dict_ = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    return dict_

def test_add(get_dict: TestDataDict) -> None:
    dict_ = get_dict
    assert myproject.main.add(dict_['a'], dict_['b']) == 3
END
$ poetry install

$ poetry shell

$ pytest  # Run the test
============================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: /home/hakon/test/python/pytest-warning/myproject
collected 1 item

tests/test_main.py .                                                                                                                                                  [100%]

============================================================================= warnings summary ==============================================================================
.:0
  :0: PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'dict' because it has a __init__ constructor (from: tests/test_main.py)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
======================================================================= 1 passed, 1 warning in 0.01s ========================================================================
```

How can I get rid of the warning: `PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'dict' because it has a __init__ constructor` ?

Comment: Isn't this just a problem of Pytest mistaking `TestDataDict` for a test case due to its `Test...` prefix? I would just pick a different name.

Comment: @chepner Yes! Seems like that is the case